# Symfony - How to load values out of EntityName.orm.yml and set them into validation.yml

Tags: php, validation, symfony, orm

Assume I have an Entity `Travel` with a string property `destination` which should have a length of 100 characters:
`Travel.php`:

```
class Travel{
    ...

    /**
    *
    * @var string
    */
    private $destination;
    ...
}
```

I allready define the length inside the `Travel.orm.yml`:

```
Project\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Travel:
  ...
  fields:
    ...
    destination:
      type: string
      length: 100
```

Right now I set the value for the validation manually inside the `validation.yml`:

```
Project\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Travel:
  properties:
    ...
    destination:
       ...
       - Length:
            max: 100
            maxMessage: ...
```

What I want now is that I just have dependence from the .orm.yml file so I just have to change values there.

How can I set the values inside the `validation.yml` dependent on the values inside the `Travel.orm.yml` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your db mapping with entity validation. Either you use annotations and have mapping and validation on the entity or remove the length on the mapping and rely only on your validation. Make sure any default mapping value is ok with your validation constraints. ex you allow 500 chars on the constraint but only 255 on the mapping

Comment: Like you figure it out the dependency is more or less already there. My question points more to _how to do that_ not _should I do that_....